# Optimization with constant ratio constraint

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve an under-determined mixing problem with optimisation in Matlab (2015). The basic problem is easy to formulate using LP with linear constraints as the mixing proportions and their sum are bound to [0,1].

min norm(Cx-d)

s.t. 0<= x_i <= 1 and sum x_i == 1.

C (n-by-m) describes the m mix ingredients characterized by n variables, d is the 1-by-n vector of a specific mix with measured concentration for each of the n variables.

Now C contains an ingredient C_k which is a 2-component mixture itself, that is constant for all N mixtures I have data for. I would like to replace the 'basic solution' assumption about the composition of C_k by including it in the formulation: I split up ingredient C_k into C_k1 and C_k2, replicate the new C N-times along the diagonal of a new larger N*n-by-N*m matrix with zeros outside of the diagonal blocks and combine all measurements by concatenating the N vectors d into a new d (1-by-N*n). 
The new sum constraint (sum x_i == N) becomes a bit weaker but the key issue is this:

The solution x contains **N ratios of x(C_k1)/x(C_k2) which should be constant**, but I do know how to add this as a constraint; or if I need to address it as a nonlinear problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If the ratio is really a constant (i,e, you know it in advance) then just write x(C_k1) = x(C_k2) * Constant.  If this constant is a variable to be determined by the model things look nonlinear to me (of course we can solve those as well).

Comment: Well, the ratio should be constant but is unknown. 
I think I understand the type of problem better now, it requires binlinear contraints. An example problem is the [Pooling Problem](http://glossary.computing.society.informs.org/ver2/mpgwiki/index.php?title=Bilinear_program&1=Pooling_problem)
The m ingredients are equivalent to pools, with most pools being equal to some source. The products is the vector x I am interested in and the demand is my measurement vector d. The constraints and objfun are different. 
But there does not seem to be a standard way for solving bilinear programs?!

Comment: It is better not to cal the ratio a constant, because well it isn't. The pooling problem is a well studied area especially because of practical pooling problems from the oil industry. Some of the current local and global NLP/QP solvers are pretty good, so we can use nonlinear solvers to attack these problems. Alternatively MIP solvers can handle large problems these days so linear approximations are also quite feasible.